# Data is not changing on the form HTML from javascript

Tags: javascript, php

thank you for fast respond.. Finally I found the function, but I still don't understand yet.

Those are the PHP function:

```
$llisting ="";

    $ct=0;

    $querye = "select leavetype.id, leavetype.ltype, leaves.newbal from leavetype,leaves where username='".$_SESSION["username"]."'";

        $resulte = pg_query($querye); 

        while ($rowe = pg_fetch_array($resulte)) {

            $ct=$ct+1;

            $lid = $rowe[id];

            $ltype = $rowe[ltype];

            $newbal = $rowe[newbal];

    /*$querye = "select id,ltype from  leavetype order by ltype";

    $resulte = pg_query($querye); 

    while ($rowe = pg_fetch_array($resulte)) {

        $ct=$ct+1;

        $lid = $rowe[id];

        $ltype = $rowe[ltype];*/

        $llisting=$llisting."<tr><td align=\"center\">$ct</td><td>$ltype</td><td><input type='text'>$newbal</td><td align=\"center\">";

        $llisting=$llisting."<select name=\"temp$lid\" id=\"temp$lid\" class=\"span12\"><option value=\"0\"> - </option> $tlisting</select>";

        $llisting=$llisting."</td></tr>\n";

        //$queryn = "Update leaves  set newbal='$newbal' where username='".$_SESSION["username"]."'";   

        //$result = pg_query($query); 
    }
```

And then this is the javascript function:

```
   function edit(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l){
        document.getElementById("frm").id.value=k7; document.getElementById("frm").name.value=a;
        document.getElementById("frm").username.value=b;
        document.getElementById("frm").emid.value=c;
        document.getElementById("frm").dob.value=d;
        setCheckedValue(document.forms['frm'].elements['gender'],e);
        document.getElementById("frm").job.value=f;
        document.getElementById("frm").info.value=g;
        document.getElementById("frm").datejoin.value=h;
        document.getElementById('locid').value=i;
        document.getElementById('deptid').value=m m;
        var myTemp = l;
        var mySplitResult = myTemp.split(",");
        for(i = 0; i < mySplitResult.length; i++){
            cval = mySplitResult[i];
            myval = cval.split("|");
            val1 = myval[0];
            val2 = myval[1];
            document.getElementById('temp'+val1).value= val2;
        }
```

And this is the html code:

```
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <div class="box">
        <div class="box-header well"><h5>Leave Information</h5></div>
        <table class="table table-hover table-condensed table-bordered" >
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th align="center">No</th>
            <th align="center">Leave Type</th>
    <th align="center">Opening Balance/Entitlement</th>
            <th align="center">Template</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        [llisting]
```

Now, I understand that I should edit the llisting function. But when I put `value='Text'` on this code:

```
$llisting=$llisting."<tr><td align=\"center\">$ct</td><td>$ltype</td><td><input type='text'>$newbal</td><td align=\"center\">";
```

The page become like this:
[image]

So the parts I don't understand are $ct, $ltype, $newbal, and why all of text field become same value after I edited. Any idea?

Comment: First understand from where function is call and also understand its parameters

Comment: this is a function and you are passing them as a parameter, so they are coming from where you are calling this function.

Comment: Please add the complete code, try using jsfiddle or codepen.io

Answer (score 0):

this is a function and you are passing them as a parameter, so they are coming from where you are calling this function.

Comment: please see my code, are the variables a...l are from $name,etc. How can they change? Or is it automatically change as the order?

Answer (score 0):

a..l variables are arguments that you pass into the function.

e.g. `edit(myVar, anotherVar, yetAnotherVar);`

and all these values are being assigned to your hidden fields.

Comment: please see my code, are the variables a...l are from $name,etc. How can they change? Or is it automatically change as the order?